Surreal numbers: proof of $\frac{1}{2}\omega + \frac{1}{2}\omega = \omega$.
I've been reading Knuth's book on Surreal Numbers, and I'd like to double check my proof.
Earlier in the book (pg. 58), Knuth proves that given $y = (Y_L, Y_R)$ if $x$ is the first number created such that $Y_L < x < Y_R$, then $y \equiv x\ \ (T8)$.
Now, when speaking of multiplication (pg. 109), we prove a result:
$ 
\frac{1}{2}x \equiv (\frac{1}{2}X_L \cup (x - \frac{1}{2}X_R), (x - \frac{1}{2}X_L) \cup \frac{1}{2}X_R)\ \ (T24)
$
Now, Knuth computes:
$
\frac{1}{2}\omega = ( (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)\ |\ ( \omega - 1, \omega - 2, \omega - 3, \omega - 4, ... ) )
$
My proof of $\frac{1}{2}\omega + \frac{1}{2}\omega = \omega$.
Now, going by addition and $T24$, we get
$
\frac{1}{2}\omega + \frac{1}{2}\omega = ( ( \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, 2, ... ) + \frac{1}{2}\omega \ |\ ( \omega - \frac{1}{2}, \omega - 1, \omega - \frac{3}{2}, ...) + \frac{1}{2}\omega)
$
Now, we can say that the left has values $\frac{1}{2}\omega + \frac{i}{2}\ \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and the right set has values $\frac{3}{2}\omega - \frac{i}{2}\ \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
Now, as per $T8$, this number has to be $\omega$ since it was created earliest ($\aleph$ day).
Is my reasoning correct here or am I completely off?
Edit: another proof on the forum.

Just prove in the game $\frac\omega2+\frac\omega2-\omega$ the second player has a winning strategy.

I've not read "Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays" unfortunately, so I'm not sure I understand your solution @Lucenaposition
